# Доступ к жесткому диску ext4 из под windows7(ntfs)

Tags: раздел, ext4, ntfs

Подскажите,как можно подключить жесткий диск ext4 в Windows7?
Дело в том,что есть второй диск(террабайтник)ext4,но у меня стоит Win7 и желания ставить Debian сейчас нет,нужно просто просмотреть диск(ext4) и если что,скопировать нужные папки себе

Answer (score 2):

Использовать ext2fsd. Загружать отсюда http://www.ext2fsd.com

Answer (score 1):

загрузитесь с лайф-сд(например ubuntu - умеет читать ntfs и ext4) смотрите и копируйте там свои файлы

Comment: какое-то извращение, учитывая наличие всевозможных ExtViewer, extXfsd, LinuxViewerov, плагинов для Far и TCMD.

Comment: появится ext5 посмотрим как будет работать это "не извращение"

Comment: @perfect , во первых в вопросе явно указан ext4. Во вторых, когда выйдет Ext5 (в стабильном виде) - допишут ExtViever и всё остальное. Буквально в две недели. Ну и плюс еще пол года ext5 будет работать как говно, если не больше, за сим юзать его надо, только если ты можешь помочь в дебаге, и не ныть что он сыпется постоянно

Answer (score 1):

И ещё для этого есть плагин в Total Commander.

Answer (score 0):

Помню был драйвер что-бы читать Ext2, не Ext4 конечно, но и видел я его достаточно давно, вполне возможно уже и под Ext4 есть сие чудо (однако он в то время весьма кривой был) :)